# Drupal Admin is not able to access edit views page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, permissions, view

I have a Drupal site and the Drupal site's admin is not able to access the edit views page.

Lately, the site has also had the problem of Content Access permissions which required me to rebuild the permissions.However, the warning that 'Content Access Permissions need to be rebuilt' continues to persist.

Whenever I goto admin>build>views page, it redirects me back to admin>build page.
Could it be a problem of content access permissions? Should I rebuild it? Would it solve the problem.Its a cumbersome process and many a times, the permissions are not built properly so I was hoping to avoid it. Is there another way of doing it than through the admin console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get redirected back to the build, it's because the path doesn't exist.

In Drupal when you go to `admin/build/views`, it try

1. `admin/build/views`
2. `admin/build`
3. `admin`

The problem is that views isn't installed, or that you need to clear the menu cache, which can be done at `admin/settings/performance`. If you needed permission, you would get an access denied page instead.

Comment: It seems that this might be located at `admin/config/development/performance` for newer Drupal installations. But clearing the cache still did not fix the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, because somehow my views UI got disabled. I enabled it again on the module page and problem solved.